# Can HTTP be used to track connections?

Tags: c#, .net, http, sockets

I know there is some debate as to whether HTTP is strictly connection-oriented or connectionless. AFAIK, HTTP only maintains a connection long enough to transmit the series of immediate requests.  Recently, a microsoft certified architect and I were discussing a method to broadcast updates to a "connected" clients.

Imagine a game of checkers.  If player1 makes a move, player2 needs to be notified.  With HTTP (no TCP/UDP), the only method I am aware of is to poll.  The architect disagreed with me.

So, how can you send updates to "connected" clients using solely HTTP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are currently 2 solutions for this:

- [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets) provide a true callback, but are not widely adopted
- Use a [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) implementation (such as [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/)). This uses polling.

Comment: Comet techniques don't use polling (except long polling, but that's not the same), but allow the server to actively send messages. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29

Comment: Polling is still polling as far as I'm concerned, compared to WebSockets at least ;)

Comment: If you get technical, but not in the way we usually interpret *polling*.

Comment: Websockets is based on TCP.  I'm not sure why he would disagree with what I said if he was thinking websockets.  Its also not widely supported, IE is not listed as a supported browser.  Comet may have been what he was thinking.

Comment: COMET techniques do perform "polling", no matter what you call it.

Comment: WebSockets can be implemented in JS and can used in IE if desired.

Answer (score 0):

At the HTTP level, you can stream data that the client can pick up on, by not specifying a Content-Length or closing the connection.
Some clients/servers have a "no data" timeout though so sending a periodic keepalive is a good idea.
Replies need to be in another HTTP request though.

An extension to the stream is the client making a connection and the server not sending any data until there is something ready. The client then processes the reply and immediatly connects again for the next chunk.